# Google OAuth 2.0 Windows App loopback is deprecated and there's no alternative

Tags: google-oauth, google-signin

Google deprecate loopback IP address flow recently, while their samples for Windows app is still using loopback IP address, and they don't provide any other alternative.
Here is their sample : https://github.com/googlesamples/oauth-apps-for-windows

[image]

How can Windows apps use Google Sign In now?

Comment: Click 'Learn more' What does it link to?

Comment: **Please stop using that sample project.**  I have been trying to get it taken down for years.  Its six years old.  No one is supporting it or updating it.

Comment: @DaImTo do you know what is the alternative to that sample project?

Comment: It depends really what are you trying to do?  are you trying to do authentication (signin) or authorization (oauth2).   What are you doing this from.  Win Forms? unity? Xamarin?

Comment: @DaImTo Would like to know an alternative solution for Winforms/WPF if possible

Comment: check out the installed app example https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth#web-applications-aspnet-mvc